# how to filter Drop down in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting

I am having

```
const Fruits = [
{ name: "Apple", code: "1" },
{ name: "Orange", code: "2" },
{ name: "Mango", code: "3" },
{ name: "Derry", code: "4" }
```

];

```
const SelectedFruits=[]
```

if user selects Apple from drop down i need to remove it from Fruits and add it to SelectedFruits like priority wise he can change them please help me and again if user can change the priority.

Comment: and if user selects other , the previous should be added again to Fruits ?

Comment: Haa yes @Codenewbie

Answer (score 1):

Hope this is what you are looking for !!

```js
const Fruits = [
{ name: "Apple", code: "1" },
{ name: "Orange", code: "2" },
{ name: "Mango", code: "3" },
{ name: "Derry", code: "4" }
];

const fruitsSel = document.querySelector('#fruits');

Fruits.forEach(function(item, index, array) {
   var opt = document.createElement("option");
   opt.text = item.name;
   opt.value = item.code;
   fruitsSel.add(opt);
});

const SelectedFruits=[];
const remainingFruits = [];
fruitsSel.addEventListener('change',(e)=>{
        const val = e.target.value;
    const selectedFruit = Fruits.filter(fruit=>fruit.code===val);
    SelectedFruits.push(...selectedFruit);
    const remFruits = Fruits.filter(fruit=>fruit.code!==val);
    remainingFruits.push(...remFruits);
    console.log({'selected fruit' : selectedFruit})
    console.log({'remaining fruits' : remFruits})
})
```

```html
<select id='fruits'>
  
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    let searchData: { [key: string]: Object; }[] = [
{ Index: "s1", Country: "Alaska" }, { Index: "s2", Country: "California" },
{ Index: "s3", Country: "Florida" }, { Index: "s4", Country: "Georgia" }
];
let filter: DropDownList = new DropDownList({
    dataSource: searchData,
    // map the appropriate column
    fields: { text: "Country", value: "Index" },
    // set placeholder to DropDownList input element
    placeholder:"Select a country",
    // set true to allowFiltering for enable filtering supports
    allowFiltering: true,
    //Bind the filter event
    filtering: function (e: FilteringEventArgs) {
        let query = new Query();
        //frame the query based on search string with filter type.
        query = (e.text != "") ? query.where("Country", "startswith", e.text, true) : query;
        //pass the filter data source, filter query to updateData method.
        e.updateData(searchData, query);
    }
});
filter.appendTo('#ddlelement');
```

you can do like this.